# Was Glenn looking for a specific ring?

Tags: comics, the-walking-dead

In the Walking Dead comic (I believe it is in issue 35 or 36, although it is hard for me to say for certain since I have the hardbound reprinting of issues 25-36), Glenn asks Tyreese and Axel to not burn any female Walker bodies.

> It turns out that this is so he can search them for a wedding ring he can give to Maggie when he proposes.

When he finds it, he says "Oh--Oh Man!  Hah!  I can't believe it!  I **found** it!  I can't **believe** I found it!  This is **it**!".

This makes it seem like he was looking for a specific one.  Was he just looking for something

> that would fit Maggie?

Or did I miss something earlier where he would have known to look for a specific ring?

Answer (score 1):

I can see how it can be interpreted as Glenn looking for something specific, but it isn't.

Recently in the story, they had been living safely in the prison with the roamers *outside* the gates. Glenn had just returned to find out that the prison had been overrun with roamers *inside*, and they had to kill off quite a few. Once they killed all of the walkers, they started to burn the bodies.

When Glenn is with Maggie, after verifying that she's okay, he smells smoke from the bodies burning. My understanding is that he just went through an ordeal, and now that they have access to a pile of bodies, it would be a good opportunity to find a ring for Maggie, who he loves. There would be no way for him to know who or what he would find-- considering the world they live in, he can't really be picky on size or quality. He obviously didn't know when he returned to the prison that the walkers would be inside and that they would have to kill so many.

The dialogue three pages before he finds the ring (from your quote) is:

> **Glenn**: Guys-- Wait! Stop for a second! Do me a--do me a favor okay?
>   **Tyrese**: What is it Glenn? What do you need? 
>  
>   **Glenn**: Don't burn-- don't burn any of the-- don't burn any of the
>   women please! I need to-- I want to look them over.

It is in [issue 35](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Issue_35) that Glenn finds the ring. In [issue 36](http://walkingdead.wikia.com/wiki/Issue_36) he shows it to Hershel, asking for permission to marry Maggie.

Essentially, I think we should read the following quote:

> **Glenn**: Oh--Oh Man! Hah! I can't believe it! I found it! I can't believe I
>   found it! This is it!

as him being so happy to find a ring for Maggie. He wasn't being picky.

From the [wiki page on Glenn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glenn_%28The_Walking_Dead%29#Comics):

> After his escape and return to the prison, he, out of his increasing love for Maggie, eventually proposed to her with a ring he stole off a zombie's finger.